# 'this' reference to item clicked erroring in ie

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7, prototypejs

For the code below, I am having some issues in IE. The second parameter passed to the function should be a reference to the item clicked. This works fine in FF and Safari, but when I tested it in IE7 it errors. IE appears to get the element (as seen in the console) but whenever I try to do anything with it I get the error:

"Object doesn't support this property or method"

Thanks for the help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.6.0.3/prototype.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/1.2/firebug-lite-compressed.js'></script>   
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">   
    var Test = {            
        doIt: function(str, btn) {  
            console.log(str);
            console.log(btn);               
            if (btn.hasClassName('red')) {
                console.log('has red');         
            } else {
                console.log('doesn\'t');
            }           
        }   
    };  
</script>   
<a href="#" onClick="Test.doIt('hello', this)" class="red">Test</a> 
</body></html>
```

Comment: "Object doesn't support this property or method (IE7Test.htm,13)"

Comment: (I copied the code into IE7Test.htm and just ran it myself)

Comment: +1 on the question for including a complete error example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that btn does not automatically have the method `hasClassName` - that's a Prototype extension.

To [extend your element with prototype extension functions](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/utility/dollar), add this line at the top of  `doIt()`:

```
btn = $(btn); // Extends element with Prototype functions.
```

Your code should work from there.

Answer (score 2):

This is because when using Prototype, elements aren't automatically extended with the Prototype functions on the page load in IE, they specifically have to pass through a `$()` call to extend the elements with these methods.  Add this to the top of your function to make it work in IE.

```
doIt : function(str, btn) {
    btn = $(btn);
}
```

**Edit:** To clarify, in all browsers other than IE 7 (iirc) and below HTML Elements will be prototyped automatically, but in IE <= 7 they must pass through the `$()` function to have these prototypes applied.